# Can Laravel's Homestead work on 32-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to use Homestead but every attempt to run Vagrant on Ubuntu 12.04 ends up with multiple **"Connection timeout. Retrying..."** warnings.

I found a lot similar posts and my guess is the problem I have may be connected to the fact that I'm trying to run Homestead on 32-bit system, while Homestead box serves 64-bit OS.

Is there any a way to get the official Laravel Homestead box to work on 32-bit system or do I need to use custom box, like **[laravel-homestead-settler-32](https://vagrantcloud.com/antoniofrignani/boxes/laravel-homestead-settler-32)?**

**UPDATE:**

I managed to run Homestead after I followed **[these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox)**. Also, thanks a lot to @OmeCoatl for the answer below which put me on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

Yes VirtualBox supports 64 bits guests in 32 bits OS hosts, the VirtualBox site explain this:

> VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit
>   host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are
>   met:
>
> You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see
>   Section 10.3, “Hardware vs. software virtualization”).
>
> You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for
>   which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not
>   supported for 64-bit VMs.
>
> If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating
>   system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the
>   particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs
>   additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon
>   explicit request.
>
> On 64-bit hosts (which typically come with hardware virtualization
>   support), 64-bit guest operating systems are always supported
>   regardless of settings, so you can simply install a 64-bit operating
>   system in the guest.

[VB docs](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)

In my own experience some BIOS doesnt support hardware virtualization, you need to see if your bios supports the hardware virtualization (and enable it).

If your host doesn't support hardware virtualization or your processor isnt 64 -bits, then you need to use the vagrant custom 32 bits box.

Comment: Thank you, this made me dig a bit more. I updated the post. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Note: If you are using Windows, you may need to enable hardware virtualization (VT-x). It can usually be enabled via your BIOS.

---> uninstall virtalbox
---> enable virtualisation via bios
---> re-install virtualbox

worked for me

Comment: While this could be useful information, I don't think it's an answer to this question which is specifically about Ubuntu.